# What does Canonical Form Means Intuitively?

Tags: diagonalization, matrix-decomposition, canonical-transformation

I have seen multiple times where canonical form is mentioned. I went to Wikipedia and as usual its quite formal definition and not intuitive at all. So the following context taken from [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixDiagonalization.html), what exactly is canonical form?

> Matrix diagonalization is equivalent to transforming the underlying system of equations into a special set of coordinate axes in which the matrix takes this canonical form.

Comment: In general, a canonical form is just a representative of an equivalence class.  Think of it as "standard form" if that helps.

Comment: @saulspatz I am not familiar with equivalence class in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me "intuitive" means "graphical" or "visual."

Here is an ellipsoid representing a general system of quadratic equations:

[image]

Here is the visual representation of that system of equations in "canonical form" (through diagonalization):

[image]

Comment: Allright so both the ellipsoid are solving same equations right?

Comment: Yep.... but where the axes have been rotated.

Comment: I see make sense, more like eigen components, right?

Comment: Yes...  at least for certain classes of equations, eigenvector decomposition is "canonical."